# reset form in hotwire

Tags: hotwire-rails, ruby-on-rails-7

As provided in an example on [the landing page](http://hotwired.dev) for hotwire, the form clearing procedure is opaque to me and also does not work.

With rails 7.0.1 installed running ruby 3.1.
the stimulus controller is set as:

```
import { Controller } from  "@hotwired/stimulus"      // "stimulus"

export default class extends Controller {
  reset() {
    this.element.reset()
  }
}
```

*note: that DHH's exaple only invokes stimulus, while the pre-installed by rails `hello-controller.js` refers to `@hotwired/stimulus`*.  Both syntassi were attempted to no avail.

The form element is structured as follows:

```
  <%= turbo_frame_tag 'new_message', target: '_top' do %>
    <%= form_with(model: [ @message.room, @message ], data: { controller: "reset_form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset_form#reset" } ) do |form| %>
        <%= form.text_field :content, class: "block shadow rounded-md border border-gray-200 outline-none px-3 py-2 mt-2 w-full" %>
        <%= form.submit 'send' %>
    <% end %>
```

I see that the submit action (*its end actually*) is the connection.  But it is not happening, while the new record is created and the UI updated as expected.

Why is this failing & how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller is named `reset_form_controller.js`.

However this is erroneously referenced with underscores

```
data: { controller: "reset_form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset_form#reset" }
```

when `reset form` should be with dashes

````
data: { controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" }```
````